# Given $a_n \to 0$, weakest condition on $b_n$ such that $a_n b_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be "some" sequence such that $a_n \to 0$.

I want to know the weakest condition  on $b_n$ which will make $a_nb_n \to 0$.

If $b_n$ is bounded then the claim is true. Can I relax this condition ?

Comment: for the second. consider $b_n = sin(n)$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @shcolf: If $b_n$ is bounded then surely $a_nb_n \to 0$. I want much weaker condition than that.

Comment: so maybe $b_n=\sqrt{n}*Sin(n)$ and $a_n=\frac{sin(n)}{n}$?

Comment: @shcolf: I want to know the theory. Many such examples can be found where both the properties are true.

Comment: If you want to find a sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that for **each** null-sequence $(a_n)_n$ also $a_n b_n \to 0$ holds, then $(b_n)_n$ must necessarily be bounded. If you want to find a sequence $(b_n)_n$ **depending on** $(a_n)_n$, this is certainly possible, but it is not clear, what kind of condition you are looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for some  sequence $\{b_n\}$ with these three properties:

1. For any $a_n \to 0$, $a_n b_n \to 0$.
2. $b_n$ is unbounded.
3. $\frac{1}{b_n} \not \to 0$.

Property (1) is equivalent to that $b_n$ is bounded.
For, suppose $b_n$ is not bounded; then we can define
$$
c_n := \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b_n} \text{ if } b_n > b_i \text{ for all } i < n \\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $c_n \to 0$ but $c_n b_n \not \to 0$, contradicting (1).

In short, (1) and (2) cannot jointly be satisfied.  The best you can get is (1) and (3), or (2) and (3) if you take "unbounded" to mean "not bounded".

Comment: @user148951 No, it is not clear.  "property of the sequence $b_n$ only?  The only way the answer can *not* depend on $a_n$ is if it works for all $a_n$, which is exactly the question I am answering here.

Comment: @Goos: When one says $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, that is property of that sequence only, it does not depend on any other thing. So, my question was for a fixed null $\{a_n\}$ is there any such condition (weaker than boundedness) on $\{b_n\}$ so that $a_nb_n \to 0$. For example, it may be that some subsequence of $\{b_n\}$ is bounded is the required condition.

Comment: @user148951 ***If the property of $\boldsymbol{b_n}$ does not depend on $\boldsymbol{a_n}$ then it holds for all $\boldsymbol{a_n}$.*** That means the ***only*** condition of the form you desire is that $b_n$ is bounded, and this cannot be relaxed.

Comment: @user148951 A followup clarification: is the condition on $b_n$ intended to be in terms of the rate of decay of $a_n$?

Comment: @Goos: understood, sorry, it is my mistake. You edit the answer otherwise I can't upvote the answer.